# php mysql: conditions for date interval with some end-date null-values

Tags: php, mysql, date, conditional-statements, intervals

I'm making a calendar, basically a list of months. When you click on a month you get a list of events taking place in that month. Most of the events have a start-date and a end-date but some of the events have null in the end-date, they only occur on a single day.

As long as an event occurs between or on the start and the end date it should show up in every month it occurs in, and they do.

The problem is, the events with a null end-date also show up on all the months that are above their start-date. How can I improve this query so that they only show up on their start-date month?

The code:

```
$sql="
SELECT id, event, date_start, date_end FROM events 
WHERE 
(year(date_start) <= $year AND month(date_start) <= $month) 
AND 
($year <= year(date_end) AND $month <= month(date_end) 
OR 
month(date_end) IS NULL)
";
```

Edit: (Problem fixed ...almost?)

```
$sql="
SELECT id, event, date_start, date_end FROM events 
WHERE 
(year(date_start) <= $year AND month(date_start) <= $month) 
AND 
($year <= year(date_end) AND $month <= month(date_end))
OR
(year(date_start) = $year AND month(date_start) = $month)";
";
```

Comment: don't allow `NULL` dates in `date-end`, but make it the same as `date-start` for 1-day events.

Comment: Not quite sure if this is what you meant but it fixed the problem, for now. I'll have to test it with multiple years also. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. the events that cross over into another year (Dec - Jan) seem to get lost somehow, but those who start in a new year Jan etc. show up.